# com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-cluster, kryo

I have a problem of deserailisation with a complex class case (see log),

Ps => despite the warning, I noticed nothing as a malfunction,

I use in my project:
akka 2.6.11 ( akka cluster , akka streams , akka pubsub )
scala 2.12,
play 2.6

log server:

```
[warn] 2020-11-30 19:09:31,504 - akka.remote.artery.Deserializer - Failed to deserialize message from [akka://application@127.0.0.1:2551] with serializer id [123454323] and manifest []. com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: can you post your `application.conf` or where you configure your deserializer. And also include more detail about your error. Your information is very generic.

Answer (score 0):

I use in my Kamon project and I think this is the cause of the excpetion,

Link project in github https://github.com/ykhilaji/play-jobs-example/

the documantion is not up to date, to launch two instances, you must launch:
node 1: ./conf/script/runNode1.sh
node 2: ./conf/script/runNode1.sh

to simulate a stress test :  ab -m POST -k -c 250 -n 2000 http://localhost/yk/jobs/10000